# Issue trying to update data in asp.net core 2.0 EF

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, modelstate, asp.net-core-2.0

Hey I've been trying for hours to figure out why I can't update properties in my database. I've been following the documentation here [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/update-related-data](http://doc)

```
var customerToUpdate = await _context.ApplicationUser
            .Include(i => i.Customer)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == id);
        if (await TryUpdateModelAsync(
            customerToUpdate,
            "",
            i => i.
```

I don't get to update any properties instead I get this [image]

I've been trying to change up my dbsets but they seem to be fine. (I guess I don't even have to make a dbset for applicationUser, but I tried with and without no difference).

[image]

My ApplicationUser has a 0-1 relationship with Customer, where customer has ApplicationUserId has primary key. It looks like this:

[image]

Really running out of things to try I hope I haven't missed something obvious. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Sounds like Intellisense issue due to `TryUpdateModelAsync<TModel>(TModel, String, Func<ModelMetadata, Boolean>)` overload. Try entering the property name manually.

Comment: Thanks it finally worked. I thought I already tried that.